# For loop not iterating?

Tags: python-3.x

I am a python newbie and I seem to be having an issue and I can't see what I am doing wrong. I am trying to make it so that when I enter a string it turns the string into pig latin. The issue is that when I do this it only prints out the first word in the string converted. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Cheers

```
def pig_latin(data):
    words = data.split()
    piglatin = []
    vowels = ["a", "i", "e", "u", "o", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
     "7", "8", "9", "0"]

    for word in words:
        if word[0] in vowels:
            word = word + "way"
        else:
            word = word.replace(word[0],"") + word[0] + "ay"
            word = word.lower()
        piglatin.append(word)

        piglatin = "".join(piglatin)
        return piglatin
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `return` statement is inside the `for` loop due to bad indentation, so obviously it will return after one iteration.
Here is the code that will fix this, along with some other changes:

```
def pigetize(text, wovels):
    return ((text + "way") if text[0] in wovels else (text[1:]+text[0]+"ay")).lower()

def pig_latin(data):
    words = data.split()
    piglatin = []
    vowels = ["a", "i", "e", "u", "o"] + [str(x) for x in range(10)]

    for word in words:
        piglatin.append(pigetize(word, wovels))

    return "".join(piglatin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your indentation. Your return statement is inside the for loop, so it would return after the first iteration. You want to make sure the `return` is at the same indent level as the `for` statement.

```
def pig_latin(data): 
    words = data.split() 
    piglatin = [] 
    vowels = ["a", "i", "e", "u", "o", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]

    for word in words:
        if word[0] in vowels:
            word = word + "way"
        else:
            word = word.replace(word[0],"") + word[0] + "ay"
            word = word.lower()
        piglatin.append(word)

    piglatin = " ".join(piglatin)
    return piglatin
```